# How to run the Google Schedule I/O 2010 Android app?

Tags: android, ui-patterns

I was trying to implement the Action Bar UI pattern for Android. For reference I checked out the Google I/O 2010 schedule app from http://code.google.com/p/iosched/. I then created an Android project from existing source where I directed eclipse to look into the checked out trunk folder. But the checked out app requires sdk version 5 which is not present in the list presented to me by the Android SDK Downloader. Also, the project is full of errors mainly for the Content Provider. My guess is probably the packages have been removed and thus they could not be resolved. Could anyone tell me how to run the Google Schedule I/O 2010 app since I intend to debug it and study how the actionbar was implemented.

Comment: If your goal is just see how the ActionBar works, you don't need to compile and run the app... just take a look at the code. I already did so and it's awesome.

Comment: Yeh I essentially did the same, I was just trying to make my life a bit easy trying to debug it

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is changing the sdk version from 5 to 7 and you are ready to go. Of course, clean the project after doing those changes.